# Simple scatter plot help: too many indicies?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following code I am trying to understand and I'm hoping it's really simple and I just don't understand it:

These are the shapes of the objects I'm working with:

```
X_train2.shape, num_eigen_pairs.shape, X_train2_pca.shape, y_train1.shape
((13626L, 18093L), (18093L, 2L), (13626L, 2L), (18093L, 2L))
```

Now I have sourced some code which will try to plot my PCA components:

```
colors = ['r', 'b', 'g']
markers = ['s', 'x', 'o']
for l, c, m in zip(np.unique(y_train1), colors, markers):
    scatter(X_train2_pca[y_train1==l, 0], X_train2_pca[y_train1==l, 1],
    c=c, label=l, marker=m)
```

However I am really struggling to understand how the indicies in this code is working and hence the below error:

> X_train2_pca[y_train1==l, 1] Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       X_train2_pca[y_train1==l, 1]
>
> IndexError: too many indices for array

Could someone help me understand what indicies I need to feed into this code based on my data shapes?

I am hoping for a chart like this (and you can see the original code):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to index *X_train2_pca*, with shape (13626L, 2L), with an indexer(*y_train1==l*) with shape (**18093L, 2L**).

*X_train2_pca* indexer should have shape (13626L, 1L).

Considering the variables names, maybe you've switched y_train**1** with y_train**2**.

Comment: Thanks @abevieiramota. X_train_pca is actually an eigen_pair dot matrix: `num_eigen_pairs = np.hstack((eigen_pairs[13626][1][:, np.newaxis], eigen_pairs[13626][1][:, np.newaxis]))`
`X_train2_pca = X_train2.T.dot(num_eigen_pairs)`

**array([[  9.05281709e-15 -1.46018722e-14j,
          9.05281709e-15 -1.46018722e-14j],
       [  7.43366618e-15 -1.58693317e-14j,
          7.43366618e-15 -1.58693317e-14j],**

How can I change it from `X_train2_pca.shape
Out[731]: (13626L, 2L)` to your suggestion of (13626, 1L)

Comment: You are indexing `X_train2_pca` to make the scatter plot. The index, `y_train1==l` must have the same size as `X_train2_pca`, but it doesn't have (`X_train2_pca` size is `13626L`, but `y_train1` size is **18093L**).
[Here](https://gist.github.com/abevieiramota/7fac765a2479b5eda77114744fbbd16d) the error is replicated.

Comment: Thank you - yep I think what you are saying is I need to apply PCA to y_train1 so it matches the same size as X_train_pca